# Apply a mask to IP with Logformat

Tags: apache, ip, masking

I need to apply a mask to IP in the log of Apache.

For example, I have this log :
192.168.234.111 - - [18/Oct/2013:16:29:40 +0200] "GET ........"

And I want to save that : 
192.168.234.xxx - - [18/Oct/2013:16:29:40 +0200] "GET ........"

To do the first log, I'm using log format like this.

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t" combined-syslog2
CustomLog /var/log/toto combined-syslog2
```

To have the second log, I can pipe a perl/shell post script like that :

```
CustomLog |/usr/local/shl/apache_syslog2
```

But I'm not happy with this solution. Is it possible to do that with Apache ?

Thanks.

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way to do it in Apache:

- Use a `RewriteCondition` which matches all IP addresses
- Store the partial IP address in a backreference
- Use a `RewriteRule` to store the partial IP plus xxx in an environment variable (e.g. `VARNAME`)
- Reference the environment variable in the `LogFormat` declaration via `%{VARNAME}e`

**References**

- [Glossary - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/glossary.html)
- [RewriteFlags: CO](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/CO)

Answer (score 6):

It can be even more simplified:

1. Just use `SetEnvIf` from module [mod_setenvif](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html) to create an environment variable based on the `Remote_Addr`.
2. Use a regular expression to determine the part you want to mask.
3. Finally reference the variable (e.g. `MASKED_IP_ADDR`) in your LogFormat statement like so:

   ```
   SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "((?:\d{1,3}\.){3})\d{1,3}" MASKED_IP_ADDR=$1XXX
   LogFormat "%{MASKED_IP_ADDR}e %l %u %t" combined-syslog2
   ```

Of course, you could also go for a correct IP address regular expression:

```
^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3})(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

This one captures the first three octets so that the last one can be substituted by `'XXX'`.